# How to place View Group at the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout

Hello I am designing one screen of my application where I require to place complete last `LinearLayout` to bottom of the screen, means `ImageViews` of that `LinearLayout` should be appear at the bottom end but currently they are not placing, Could you please see what could be reason for this. What it is correct way to do this

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.audiostreet.LoginActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_dans_ma_rue" />

        <com.example.customview.TextViewWithCustomFont
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/login_screen_app_tex_vertical_margin"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textSize="@dimen/login_screen_app_text_size" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/login_main_drawable" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/facebookButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/buttons_vertical_margin"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/fb_button" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/twitterButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/buttons_vertical_margin"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/twitter_button" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/emailButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/buttons_vertical_margin"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/email_button" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Currently it is looking like this and I want all three `ImageViews` should appear from bottom of the screen.

Tablet 7 inch

[image]

Tablet 10 inch

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.audiostreet.LoginActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/loading" />

    <com.example.customview.TextViewWithCustomFont
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/loading" />
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
    ></LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/facebookButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/loading" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/twitterButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/loading" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/emailButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/loading" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Do you really need ScrollView? If not than try this, otherwise scroll view will try to get minimum height of view, and my placeholder will be flattened.

Alternative is to put Buttons under ScrollView.

Last solution i see, if you really need anything in scrollView, than try to Generate your own LinearLayout and than place views on your own.

Comment: I tried your solution but it is not working, still showing same as like it was

Comment: You removed scrollView? As i said, scrollView forces lowest possible height, if you remove it, than my solution will work. That's why I asked if you really need that scrollView.

Comment: Yes, I removed ScrollView

Comment: Than you missed something, copy all my code and check this way. Root linearLayout has height set to Match_Parent, if i set it to wrap_content than it will won't work, so maybe you missed that detail?

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.audiostreet.LoginActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_dans_ma_rue" />

        <com.example.customview.TextViewWithCustomFont
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/login_screen_app_tex_vertical_margin"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textSize="@dimen/login_screen_app_text_size" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/login_main_drawable" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/facebookButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/buttons_vertical_margin"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/fb_button" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/twitterButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/buttons_vertical_margin"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/twitter_button" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/emailButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/buttons_vertical_margin"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/email_button" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```